# MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column ' ____ ' in 'field list'

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I get the following MySQL exception:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'book.call_Number' in 'field list'.

What does that mean and how can I solve it?

Here is the code responsible for this exception:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    list.clearSelection();

    String selectString = " ";
    String afName = auth_fName.getText();
    String aMI = auth_MI.getText();
    String alName = auth_lName.getText();
    String tField = titleField.getText();
    String sField = subjectField.getText();

    try {
        Connection conn = Database.getConnection();

        Statement s = conn.createStatement();

        if (!afName.equals("") && (!aMI.equals("")) && (!alName.equals("")) && (!tField.equals("")) && (!sField.equals(""))) {
            selectString = "SELECT a.call_Number as callNbr "
                + "FROM book a "
                + "FULL JOIN transaction b "
                + "ON a.call_Number=b.call_Number";
        }

        s = conn.createStatement();
        System.out.println(selectString);
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(selectString);

        while (rs.next()) {
            String call_Num = rs.getString("call_Number");
            String title = rs.getString("title");
            String auth_lName = rs.getString("auth_lName");
            String auth_MI = rs.getString ("auth_MI");
            String auth_fName = rs.getString("auth_fName");
            String availability = rs.getString("availability");

            view = new View(call_Num, title, auth_lName, auth_MI, auth_fName, availability);
            vList.add(view);
            System.out.println(view);
        }

        rs.close();
        s.close();
        conn.close();

        list.setListData(vList.toArray());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is the DDL and content:

```
s.executeUpdate (
    "CREATE TABLE book ("
    + "call_Number CHAR(10),"
    + "PRIMARY KEY (call_Number),"
    + "auth_fName CHAR(30)NOT NULL, auth_MI CHAR(2),"
    + "auth_lName CHAR(50)NOT NULL, title CHAR(100) NOT NULL,"
    + "subject CHAR(30) NOT NULL)");
count = s.executeUpdate (
    "INSERT INTO book"
    + " VALUES"
    + "('MY.111.000', 'Mark', 'M','Bradshaw','Mystery Under the Sun','mystery'),"
    + "('MY.111.001', 'Mark','','Twain','The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn','mystery'),"
    + "('SF.111.002', 'Kito', 'M','Bradford','Mr. Roboto','science fiction'),"
    + "('SF.111.003', 'Eric','','Laslow','Science Fiction - Can It Happen?','science fiction'),"
    + "('AV.111.004', 'Rashad','','Cheeks','Fire Under the Bridge','adventure'),"
    + "('AV.111.005', 'Samantha','A','Appleby','The Open Sea','adventure'),"
    + "('CO.111.006', 'Lindsey', '','Butterby','What? We cant spend anymore!?','comedy'),"
    + "('CO.111.007', 'Judy', 'S','Yates','So this is life?','comedy'),"
    + "('IN.111.008', 'Elizabeth', 'J','Lee','Mystery Under the Sun','international'),"
    + "('IN.111.009', 'Gabriella', 'M','Rodriguez','Love in Brazil','international')");
```

*********t_action table*************************************************

```
  //create transaction table
        s.executeUpdate (
            "CREATE TABLE t_action ("
            + "patron_ID CHAR(10) NOT NULL,"
            + "call_Number CHAR(10) NOT NULL, check_Out_Date DATE NOT NULL, check_In_Date DATE NOT NULL,"
            + "PRIMARY KEY (patron_ID, call_Number),"
            + "avail CHAR(15), total_Charge FLOAT)");

        count3 = s.executeUpdate (
            "INSERT INTO t_action"
            + " VALUES"
            + "('P222200000','MY.111.000','2011-03-08','2011-03-15','AVAILABLE',5.00),"
            + "('P222200001','MY.111.001','2011-03-31','2011-04-6','DUE 2011-04-6',5.00),"
            + "('P222200002','SF.111.002','2011-03-30','2011-04-5','DUE 2011-04-5',5.00),"
            + "('P222200003','SF.111.003','2011-03-29','2011-04-4','DUE 2011-04-4',5.00),"
            + "('P222200004','AV.111.004','2011-03-28','2011-04-3','DUE 2011-04-3',5.00),"
            + "('P222200005','AV.111.005','2011-03-27','2011-04-2','DUE 2011-04-2',5.00),"
            + "('P222200006','CO.111.006','2011-03-26','2011-04-1','DUE 2011-04-1',5.00),"
            + "('P222200007','CO.111.007','2011-01-06','2011-01-12','AVAILABLE',5.00),"
            + "('P222200008','IN.111.008','2011-02-06','2011-02-12','AVAILABLE',5.00),"
            + "('P222200009','IN.111.009','2011-03-06','2011-03-12','AVAILABLE',5.00)");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `<column> as` predicate like below:-

`selectString = "SELECT a.call_Number as callNbr, ... "
                                            + "FROM book a"
                                            + "FULL JOIN transaction b"
                                            + "ON a.call_Number=b.call_Number";`

And then change the code to look for `callNbr` :-

`String call_Num = rs.getString("callNbr");`

HTH.

Comment: Hahahahaha! When I take out the alias and just do call_Number I get: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'call_Number' in field list is ambiguous                  . . . loosing hair to pull out :)

Comment: Alright that means the call_Number column is in both tables which I should have noticed from your join. My bad! Can you please try the column name as approach like `SELECT call_Number as callNbr` ?

Comment: When I do that i get this again: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'call_Number' in field list is ambiguous. . . I will update my post with the revised call to make sure I am doing it right.

Comment: I thought I did?  I entered it as:  selectString = "SELECT call_Number as callNbr, title, auth_lName, auth_fName, auth_MI, transaction.availability "
                                            + "FROM book "
                                            + "FULL JOIN transaction "
                                            + "ON book.call_Number=transaction.call_Number";

Comment: Double check the original code that I posted.  I edited it to show the revised code with your suggestion about the variable callNbr.  Did I implement it the way you intended?

Comment: Try this: `SELECT a.call_Number as callNbr " + "FROM book a" + "FULL JOIN transaction b" + "ON a.call_Number=b.call_Number`

Comment: Hey CoolBeans, this is what I get now: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FULL JOIN transaction b ON a.call_Number=b.call_Number' at line 1 . . . mySQL is demon software :)      I will edit the code above to show you exactly the way it looks in my code.

Comment: No need to revise your post .. I am not sure why that sql would be incorrect. It's a standard sql. Let's go back to using the table name alias but this time we will still have the column name as predicate too. So try this now: `SELECT book.call_Number as callNbr " + "FROM book" + "FULL JOIN transaction " + "ON book.call_Number=transaction.call_Number`

Comment: This is what I get now: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'book.call_Number' in 'field list'.  I did a system.out.println(selectString) to see the command that was actually going to mySQL, it seems correct: SELECT book.call_Number as callNbr FROM book FULL JOIN transaction ON book.call_Number=transaction.call_Number

Comment: You missed updating the java syntax. It should be:- `String call_Num = rs.getString("callNbr");`

Comment: Okay, when I followed Serge's suggestion it worked...when I remove the transaction.availability.So how can I get it to work taking in the transaction table as well. I revised the availability column to be 'avail' & the transaction table to be 't_action'.Now I have the code: selectString = "SELECT a.call_Number, title, auth_lName, auth_fName, auth_MI, b.t_action.avail " + "FROM book a " + "INNER JOIN t_action b "+ "ON a.call_Number=b.call_Number";  Of course, whenever, I enter it it gives me a very familiar error: Unknown column 'b.t_action.avail' in 'field list'.Any ideas how to get around it?

Comment: Also, I only want it to choose the particular record that I search for?  Am I using the right mySQL command to do that?  I take the values from most of the book table and combine them to on value from the t_action table. Is that right? I am trying to avoid redundancy . . .

Answer (score 3):

Change your query to this:

```
    selectString = "SELECT a.call_Number "
        + "FROM book a "
        + "INNER JOIN transaction b "
        + "ON a.call_Number=b.call_Number";
```

MySQL does not support `FULL OUTER JOIN`. If you really need the effect of that - you'll need 2 selects with a `UNION`. Although from looks of it - does not seem like that would be necessary.

Comment: Okay, when I followed your suggestion it worked...when I remove the transaction.availability.So how can I get it to work taking in the transaction table as well. I revised the availability column to be 'avail' & the transaction table to be 't_action'.Now I have the code: selectString = "SELECT a.call_Number, title, auth_lName, auth_fName, auth_MI, b.t_action.avail " + "FROM book a " + "INNER JOIN t_action b "+ "ON a.call_Number=b.call_Number";  Of course, whenever, I enter it it gives me a very familiar error: Unknown column 'b.t_action.avail' in 'field list'.Any ideas how to get around it?

Comment: Also, I only want it to choose the particular record that I search for?  Am I using the right mySQL command to do that?  I take the values from most of the book table and combine them to on value from the t_action table. Is that right? I am trying to avoid redundancy . . .

Comment: That's incorrect. It should be `b.avail` not `b.t_action.avail`.

Comment: @Mike - I would write the SQL this way for what you are asking - `"SELECT <your_columns> "
        + "FROM book a,transaction b "
        + "WHERE a.call_Number=b.call_Number";`

Comment: That's what I originally did without the cool 'a' and 'b' thing.  Well, it is working now;however, it prints out the contents of the specified columns for all the items in the table.  It is more than one value.  Any ideas?  I am using the statement that you specified above:  selectString = "a.call_Number, title, auth_lName, auth_fName, auth_MI, b.avail "
                                            + "FROM book a,t_action b "
                                            + "WHERE a.call_Number=b.call_Number";

Comment: There should only be one value that it should return.

Comment: . . . or rather one row of information that it should return (not multiple).

Comment: Since you don't have a where statement that would restrict it to one specific result you're looking for - you should be getting one row for every combination of book & associated transaction.